# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't open saved projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm just starting off with VS (2015 version) (C++ in general) and, knowing my luck, I immediately stumble upon an issue: VS 2015 doesn't open saved projects. I believe that it loads them up but doesn't bother to view them. I can't really describe it in words so I'll post a GIF. Any and all help would be appreciated.

[image: A gif to show my problem]

[A more detailed GIF](https://i.imgur.com/ZYsBxXr.gifv)

Comment: ... I forgot to change the title from the saved draft.

Comment: @philosophicalintrovert That's a horrible question. Watching the gif video is irritating. You should describe the steps you have taken in your question as text please. As is that's not really useful.

Comment: Why do I think that the Gif is nice actually and informative? Saved time and prevented OP from making writing mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the right side of your screen there should be a vertical tab called "Solution Explorer".

Clicking on it reveals your solution, its projects, and all the files associated with it. From there you should be able to find the files.

If you still can't find the files, it is likely that you didn't include them. You can add them to a directory in "Solution Explorer" by `Right-clicking -> Add -> New Item -> C++ File`

---

This happens when you close every tab in your project, and because VS saves the state of your tabs, when you reopen the project, they are all closed.

Also note that by default, when creating a whole new project, there are no files to open, so the screen will also be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the shortcut key to show the solution explorer.  Ctrl-Alt-L by default I believe.